# Keyboard shortcuts Customization

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created keyboard shortcuts menu,same as like this stackoverflow keyboard shortcuts.In multilevel.

> Scenario

```
In first level i have assigned functions for only key A.

In the second level i have assigned functions for B & C keys
```

I have controlled key events B & c in the first level with a variable.

Its working fine.I would like to know is there any better way of doing it.

```js
var level= 0;
$('body').keypress(function(e){
  level == 1 ?(
(((e.keyCode == 66 || e.keyCode == 98)  && level==1 )? (alert("B"),level=2,$('#screen3').show()) : ""),
(((e.keyCode == 67 || e.keyCode == 99)  && level==1 )? (alert("c"),level=2,$('#screen3').show()) : "")
):"";
level == 0 ?((e.keyCode == 65 || e.keyCode == 97) ? level = 1 : level =0):"";
level == 1 ?($('#screen1').hide(),$('#screen2').show()):(level =2 ?$('#screen2').hide():(level= 0));
});
```

```css
#screen1,#screen2,#screen3 {
background-color: black;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
position: fixed;
left: 10px;
top: 10px;
padding: 10px;
text-align: left;
border-radius: 6px;
z-index: 1000;
  color:white ;
}

:matches(#screen1,#screen2) pre kbd {
display: inline-block;
font-family: monospace;
}
kbd {
padding: .1em .6em;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
font-size: 11px;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
color: #333;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 0 0 2px #fff inset;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 0 .1em;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
line-height: 1.4;
white-space: nowrap;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="screen1" style="">
  <pre>Keyboard shortcuts:
<b><kbd>A</kbd> alert</b>
</pre></div>
<div id="screen2" style="display:none">
  <pre>Keyboard shortcuts:
<b><kbd>B</kbd> alert Key - B</b>
<b><kbd>C</kbd> alert Key - C</b>
</pre></div>
<div id="screen3" style="display:none">
  <pre>Thats it Folks!!
</pre></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Right off the bat, your code needs some serious indentation. It's barely readable given its current state. If you happen to use Sublime Text, there's [HTML-CSS-JS Prettify](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/HTML-CSS-JS%20Prettify) plugin.

Another thing I noticed is you're loading jQuery *twice*.

Next, your code is highly coupled. Your condition to check the buttons are highly coupled to the behavior it does. What would happen if I want to change the behavior to another key? Or what if you want to operate in another platform which uses different keyboard norms (Mac vs PC)? You can read [Game Programming Patterns](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/command.html) to get an idea of configurable keys.

Another thing to consider is what if the user wants to bail out of a level? What if the user accidentally pressed a button that progressed him a level, but wants to go back and use another combination instead? Usually <kbd>Esc</kbd> was reserved for this. For multi-press button combinations, releasing all buttons is an option.

jQuery also has [`event.which`](https://api.jquery.com/event.which/) which is a normalized version of `charCode` and `keyCode`.

Your code lives in the global space, which means `level` is highly modifiable and pollutes the global namespace. You could put your code inside a closure, an IIFE to be exact, to prevent that.